# Calculate how much of a trajectory/path falls in-between two other trajectories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

In a broad sense, I'm trying to calculate how much of the red path/trajectory falls in-between the black paths for many different trials (see plot below).
I circled a couple examples, where for (0, 1, 3) approx 30-40% of the red path falls in-between the two black paths, but for (2, 1, 3) only about 1-2% of the red path is in-between the two black paths.

[image]

I have two dataframes, df_R & df_H.

df_R contains the position data for the red paths (in X & Z). Note that X & Z are both positional/spatial data. These data do not have a date/time-like index. Also note that this is 2D data from a Unity Application (for some reason X & Z are the equivalent of Y & X). All paths/trajectories are 1000 points in length in both dataframes.

Preview of df_R:

```
    (0, 1, 1)_mean_X  (0, 1, 1)_mean_Z  ...  (2, 2, 3)_mean_X  (2, 2, 3)_mean_Z
0         -15.856713          5.002617  ...        -15.600160         -5.010470
1         -15.831320          5.003529  ...        -15.566172         -5.012251
2         -15.805927          5.004441  ...        -15.532184         -5.014032
3         -15.780534          5.005353  ...        -15.498196         -5.015814
4         -15.755141          5.006265  ...        -15.464208         -5.017595
..               ...               ...  ...               ...               ...
95        -12.818362          5.429729  ...        -12.391177         -5.391595
96        -12.783905          5.437335  ...        -12.357563         -5.396919
97        -12.749456          5.444990  ...        -12.323950         -5.402243
98        -12.715017          5.452697  ...        -12.290336         -5.407567
99        -12.680594          5.460469  ...        -12.256722         -5.412891
```

df_H contains the position data for the black paths, which includes a 'top' and 'bottom' column for X and for Z, corresponding to the two black paths in each plot.

Preview of df_H:

```
    (0, 1, 1)_top_X  (0, 1, 1)_bottom_X  ...  (2, 2, 3)_top_Z  (2, 2, 3)_bottom_Z
0        -16.000000          -16.000000  ...        -5.000000           -5.000000
1        -16.000000          -16.000000  ...        -5.000000           -5.000000
2        -16.000000          -16.000000  ...        -5.000000           -5.000000
3        -16.000000          -16.000000  ...        -5.000000           -5.000000
4        -16.000000          -16.000000  ...        -5.000000           -5.000000
..              ...                 ...  ...              ...                 ...
95       -15.000971          -15.417215  ...        -4.993461           -5.011372
96       -14.979947          -15.402014  ...        -4.993399           -5.013007
97       -14.957949          -15.385840  ...        -4.993291           -5.014463
98       -14.934171          -15.368649  ...        -4.993186           -5.015692
99       -14.908484          -15.349371  ...        -4.993069           -5.016940
```

I need to see whether the X/Z value in df_R falls within the range of the X/Z values in df_H. However, the solution needs to NOT rely on time or index (or row-wise comparisons).

I have been trying to implement this for a while but am stuck. This is what I've been trying but it's not working because it relies on time.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def CI_analysis(df_H, df_R):
    
    # separate X & Z 
    df_H_top_X = df_H.filter(regex='top_X')
    df_H_bottom_X = df_H.filter(regex='bottom_X')
    
    df_H_top_Z = df_H.filter(regex='top_Z')
    df_H_bottom_Z = df_H.filter(regex='bottom_Z')
    
    df_R_X = CI_raycast.filter(regex='mean_X') 
    df_R_Z = CI_raycast.filter(regex='mean_Z') 
    
    # check if X is within the range of top & bottom X
    CI_inside_X = pd.DataFrame()
    for col in df_R_X:
        temp = []
        c = 0
        for i, val in df_R_X[col].iteritems():
            if (val < df_H_top_X.iloc[i,c]) & (val > df_H_bottom_X.iloc[i,c]):
                temp.append(1)
            else: 
                temp.append(0)
        CI_inside_X[col] = temp
        c = c+1

    # check if Z is within the range of top & bottom Z
    CI_inside_Z = pd.DataFrame()
    for col in df_R_Z:
        temp = []
        # print(col)
        c = 0
        for i, val in df_R_Z[col].iteritems():
            if (val < df_H_top_Z.iloc[i,c]) & (val > df_H_bottom_Z.iloc[i,c]):
                temp.append(1)
            else: 
                temp.append(0)
        CI_inside_Z[col] = temp
        c = c+1

    # Check if X & Z were both in-between the top & bottom trajectories
    CI_inside = pd.DataFrame()
    for col in CI_inside_X:
        temp = []
        c = 0
        for i,row in CI_inside_X[col].iteritems(): 
            if (row == 1) & (CI_inside_Z.iloc[i,c] == 1):
                temp.append(1)
            else: 
                temp.append(0)
        CI_inside[col] = temp
        c = c+1
    
    CI_inside_avg = pd.DataFrame(CI_inside.mean(axis=0)).transpose() 
    
    return CI_inside_X, CI_inside_Z, CI_inside, CI_inside_avg
```

Lastly, here is code to reproduce the two dataframes df_R & df_H (with random numbers):

```
df_R_cols = ['(0, 1, 1)_mean_X', '(0, 1, 1)_mean_Z', '(0, 1, 2)_mean_X',
       '(0, 1, 2)_mean_Z', '(0, 1, 3)_mean_X', '(0, 1, 3)_mean_Z',
       '(0, 2, 1)_mean_X', '(0, 2, 1)_mean_Z', '(0, 2, 2)_mean_X',
       '(0, 2, 2)_mean_Z', '(0, 2, 3)_mean_X', '(0, 2, 3)_mean_Z',
       '(1, 1, 1)_mean_X', '(1, 1, 1)_mean_Z', '(1, 1, 2)_mean_X',
       '(1, 1, 2)_mean_Z', '(1, 1, 3)_mean_X', '(1, 1, 3)_mean_Z',
       '(1, 2, 1)_mean_X', '(1, 2, 1)_mean_Z', '(1, 2, 2)_mean_X',
       '(1, 2, 2)_mean_Z', '(1, 2, 3)_mean_X', '(1, 2, 3)_mean_Z',
       '(2, 1, 1)_mean_X', '(2, 1, 1)_mean_Z', '(2, 1, 2)_mean_X',
       '(2, 1, 2)_mean_Z', '(2, 1, 3)_mean_X', '(2, 1, 3)_mean_Z',
       '(2, 2, 1)_mean_X', '(2, 2, 1)_mean_Z', '(2, 2, 2)_mean_X',
       '(2, 2, 2)_mean_Z', '(2, 2, 3)_mean_X', '(2, 2, 3)_mean_Z'] 

df_H_cols = ['(0, 1, 1)_top_X', '(0, 1, 1)_bottom_X', '(0, 1, 1)_top_Z',
       '(0, 1, 1)_bottom_Z', '(0, 1, 2)_top_X', '(0, 1, 2)_bottom_X',
       '(0, 1, 2)_top_Z', '(0, 1, 2)_bottom_Z', '(0, 1, 3)_top_X',
       '(0, 1, 3)_bottom_X', '(0, 1, 3)_top_Z', '(0, 1, 3)_bottom_Z',
       '(0, 2, 1)_top_X', '(0, 2, 1)_bottom_X', '(0, 2, 1)_top_Z',
       '(0, 2, 1)_bottom_Z', '(0, 2, 2)_top_X', '(0, 2, 2)_bottom_X',
       '(0, 2, 2)_top_Z', '(0, 2, 2)_bottom_Z', '(0, 2, 3)_top_X',
       '(0, 2, 3)_bottom_X', '(0, 2, 3)_top_Z', '(0, 2, 3)_bottom_Z',
       '(1, 1, 1)_top_X', '(1, 1, 1)_bottom_X', '(1, 1, 1)_top_Z',
       '(1, 1, 1)_bottom_Z', '(1, 1, 2)_top_X', '(1, 1, 2)_bottom_X',
       '(1, 1, 2)_top_Z', '(1, 1, 2)_bottom_Z', '(1, 1, 3)_top_X',
       '(1, 1, 3)_bottom_X', '(1, 1, 3)_top_Z', '(1, 1, 3)_bottom_Z',
       '(1, 2, 1)_top_X', '(1, 2, 1)_bottom_X', '(1, 2, 1)_top_Z',
       '(1, 2, 1)_bottom_Z', '(1, 2, 2)_top_X', '(1, 2, 2)_bottom_X',
       '(1, 2, 2)_top_Z', '(1, 2, 2)_bottom_Z', '(1, 2, 3)_top_X',
       '(1, 2, 3)_bottom_X', '(1, 2, 3)_top_Z', '(1, 2, 3)_bottom_Z',
       '(2, 1, 1)_top_X', '(2, 1, 1)_bottom_X', '(2, 1, 1)_top_Z',
       '(2, 1, 1)_bottom_Z', '(2, 1, 2)_top_X', '(2, 1, 2)_bottom_X',
       '(2, 1, 2)_top_Z', '(2, 1, 2)_bottom_Z', '(2, 1, 3)_top_X',
       '(2, 1, 3)_bottom_X', '(2, 1, 3)_top_Z', '(2, 1, 3)_bottom_Z',
       '(2, 2, 1)_top_X', '(2, 2, 1)_bottom_X', '(2, 2, 1)_top_Z',
       '(2, 2, 1)_bottom_Z', '(2, 2, 2)_top_X', '(2, 2, 2)_bottom_X',
       '(2, 2, 2)_top_Z', '(2, 2, 2)_bottom_Z', '(2, 2, 3)_top_X',
       '(2, 2, 3)_bottom_X', '(2, 2, 3)_top_Z', '(2, 2, 3)_bottom_Z']

df_R = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 36)), columns=df_R_cols)
df_H = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 72)), columns=df_H_cols)
```

Comment: you may want to consider shapely and/or geopandas for this task.  It is a package that already has notions of shapes, areas, intersections etc, but I don't know if your task is possible or not.

Comment: is this 2D data? I am slightly confused by the terms X and Z. Typically in 2D X and Y are used; so asking to see if something else is going on here.

Comment: @Tommy Yes it is 2D data. It from a Unity Application and for some reason X & Z are the equivalent of Y & X .

Comment: Do you have the X values of the discretized points at the same values of Y for each 3-pair? IE, x_black1, x_Red1, x_black2, all for the exact same values of Y? Think of it as putting horizontal lines; do all 3 points fall on the horizontal lines?

Comment: @Tommy Actually I dont think all the X values would necessarily be at the same values of Y for each pair since the application just samples 2D position at 50Hz. In df_R, mean_X & mean_Z are 'x_red' and 'z_red'. In df_H, top_X and top_Z are x_black1 and z_black1, and bottom_X and bottom_Z are x_black2 and z_black2. All trajectories are 1000 points in length.

Comment: the approach i was thinking was an approx approach as follows. Discretize your Y (vertical) space into a horizontal buckets. IE if the Y axis is from 0 to 100, then 0 to .01, .01 to .02, etc ( that would be 10000 buckets). Then, place all X values in their horizontal buckets according to the Y. Finally, the ratio you seek is `number of rows where x_black1 <= x_Red <= x_black2 / total buckets`. If all your Y values are aligned already, this should be not to bad to do? It might be easiest to do this outside of pandas datatrames

Comment: even a simple dict, or list of buckets: `[(x_b1, x_r, x_b2),....]` where each 3-tuple is for the same Y value; then compute the ratio. IE; read your data frames and dump them into this bucketized structure

Comment: @Tommy Looking at my data, each 3-pair of X values doesnt occur at the same exact values of Y (since Y is just positional data sampled at 50 Hz). How could I adapt this solution in this case?

Comment: Thats why I say "buckets" and not finite points in space. You can break up the Y axis into sections. A Red Y value of 1.02 might get bucketed with X values of 1.03 and 1.01 depending on the bucket size (1, .1, .01,... depends on `range(Y)`. The ratio would be  `number of rows where x_black1 <= x_Red <= x_black2 / total buckets with 3 points`;  (i dont know if its possible that some rows will not have x_b1,x_r,x_b2 in it)

Comment: @Tommy Ok yes I think this could work. No idea how to break up the Y data into buckets but will try and implement this.

Comment: here's a picture I made for you   https://imgur.com/a/32XDRvK the index of each bucket will be like `floor(Yval / bucket_size)` or something like that

Comment: @Tommy Thank you, makes sense and seems very promising

Comment: Start and end points are always the same?  Is there any reason you can't rotate/scale all three channels to be on the interval `[(0,0),(0,1)]`and then just . . . count the datapoints in between?

Comment: @DanielF The start and end points aren't the same for all trajectories

Comment: But for each trajectory that are the same for the black and red lines, right?

Comment: @DanielF Within each group they are close but slightly different.

Comment: Can you provide one of the top, bottom, average, X, Z datasets?  I assume they are much more smooth and regular than the random test data will be.

Comment: can you please provide real data? Random numbers are quite different than your actual data.  You can use `df_R.to_dict()` if that helps.  Please truncate appropriately but make sure we can actually reproduce the problem with the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just a idea**

If i understand the discussion right, the problem is that the data was sampled at different points. So you can't just compare the value of each row. And sometimes the buttom line is switched with the top line.

My idea would be now to interpolate the black trajectories at the same x-values as the red trajectorie. My answer concentrates on that idea. I borrowed some code from the previous answers for iterating over the data sets.

```
    df_H = pd.read_pickle('df_H.pickle')
    df_R = pd.read_pickle('df_R.pickle')
    dfh_groups = [df_H.columns[x:x + 4] for x in range(0, len(df_H.columns), 4)]
    dfr_groups = [df_R.columns[x:x + 2] for x in range(0, len(df_R.columns), 2)]
    df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Percentage'])

    for i in range(len(dfr_groups)):

        label = dfr_groups[i][0].split('_')[0]

        X_R = df_R[dfr_groups[i][0]].to_numpy()
        Y_R = df_R[dfr_groups[i][1]].to_numpy()
        X_H_Top = df_H[dfh_groups[i][0]].to_numpy()
        Y_H_Top = df_H[dfh_groups[i][1]].to_numpy()
        X_H_Bottom = df_H[dfh_groups[i][2]].to_numpy()
        Y_H_Bottom = df_H[dfh_groups[i][3]].to_numpy()

        # Interpolate df_H to match the data points from df_R
        bottom = interpolate.interp1d(X_H_Bottom,Y_H_Bottom)
        top = interpolate.interp1d(X_H_Top,Y_H_Top)

        # Respect the interpolation boundaries, so drop every row not in range from X_H_(Bottom/Top)
        X_H_Bottom = X_R[(X_R > np.amin(X_H_Bottom)) & (X_R < np.amax(X_H_Bottom))]
        X_H_Top = X_R[(X_R > np.amin(X_H_Top)) & (X_R < np.amax(X_H_Top))]
        minimal_X = np.intersect1d(X_H_Bottom, X_H_Top)

        # Calculate the new values an the data points from df_R
        Y_I_Bottom = bottom(minimal_X)
        Y_I_Top = top(minimal_X)

        #Plot
        '''
        plt.plot(X_R, Y_R,'r-',minimal_X, Y_I_Bottom,'k-', minimal_X, Y_I_Top,'k-')
        plt.show()
        '''

        # Count datapoints of df_R within bottom and top
        minimal_x_idx = 0
        nr_points_within = 0
        for i in range(0,len(X_R)):
            if minimal_x_idx >= len(minimal_X):
                break
            elif X_R[i] != minimal_X[minimal_x_idx]:
                continue
            else:
                # Check if datapoint within even if bottom and top changed
                if (Y_R[i] > np.amin(Y_I_Bottom[minimal_x_idx]) and  Y_R[i] < np.amax(Y_I_Top[minimal_x_idx]))\
                        or (Y_R[i] < np.amin(Y_I_Bottom[minimal_x_idx]) and  Y_R[i] > np.amax(Y_I_Top[minimal_x_idx])):
                    nr_points_within += 1
                minimal_x_idx += 1

        # Depends on definition if points outside of interpolation range should be count as outside or be dropped
        percent_within = (nr_points_within * 100) / len(minimal_X)
        df_result.loc[label] = [percent_within]
    print(df_result)
```

I think and i really hope there are way more elegant ways to implement it especially the for-loop at the end.

I tested on it a few it worked quite well at least at a first glance. For your marked ones i got 71.8%(0,1,3) and 0,8%(2,1,3) that fall within.

I just compared each row after the interpolation. But at this point you could go a step further. For example you could get the spline interpolation coefficients and than calculate the intersections of the trajectories. So you could calculate either the percentage of a projection onto the x-Axis or really the percentage of length of the trajectorie that falls within. Maybe with a nice error estimation. I hoped that helped i little bit.

**Little more detailed explaination based on comment**

First i renamed your Z-Axis Y in my variables and in the explaination, i hope that's not too confusing. With the scipy function [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) i do a [spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) of the bottom/top trajectories. Basically what that means i model two mathematical function based on the given X/Y values of the bottom and top trajectories. These functions return continuous ouput either for bottom or top. On every X value i get the Y value from the trajectorie even for X values that do not appear in the data. That's done by a so called spline interpolation. Between every X/Y value pair in the data a line is calculated (m * x +t). You can also use the keyword 'cubic' than a second degree polygon (a * x^2 + b * x + c) is calculated. Now with this model i can look, which value the bottom and top trajectories have at the X values given by the red trajectorie.

But this method has its limits that's why i need to drop some values. The interpolation is only defined between the min and the max of the X values given by the dataset. For example if the red trajectorie has smaller minimal X Value x1 than the bottom trajectorie in the dataset, i can not get the corresponding Y Value for x1, because the interpolation of the bottom trajectorie is not defined at x1. Therefor i limit myself to range in which a know every trajectorie in which my interolation is well defined for bottom and top.

*PS.:*
Here my output for the whole dataset:

```
           Percentage
(0, 1, 1)    3.427419
(0, 1, 2)   76.488396
(0, 1, 3)   71.802618
(0, 2, 1)    6.889564
(0, 2, 2)   16.330645
(0, 2, 3)   59.233098
(1, 1, 1)   13.373860
(1, 1, 2)   45.262097
(1, 1, 3)   91.084093
(1, 2, 1)    0.505051
(1, 2, 2)    1.010101
(1, 2, 3)   41.253792
(2, 1, 1)    4.853387
(2, 1, 2)   12.916246
(2, 1, 3)    0.808081
(2, 2, 1)    0.101112
(2, 2, 2)    0.708502
(2, 2, 3)   88.810484
```

Comment: Yup this returns values that seem to make sense! Can you explain what you're doing when you "drop every row not in range from X_H_(Bottom/Top)"? What does it mean to interpolate the black trajectories at the same x-values as the red trajectories?

Comment: I added a little explaination based onn your comment at the end of the answer. I hope that clarifies it a littlebit.

Comment: awesome your explanation was very helpful, thank you. Is there any way you could edit your code to apply your solution to the entire dataset and output all the percent withins in one go?

Comment: I updated my code. Generates the percentage for all Sets now.

Comment: your code produces values that make sense for the given set of data, thus I awarded you the bounty. The previous answers also helped to elucidate the problem much more fully than I could. Cheers to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

- This solution implements the code from the OP in a more efficient manner, and does what is **asked** for, but not what is **wanted**.
- While the solution doesn't provide the desired result, after discussion with the OP, we decided to leave this answer, because it helps to clarify the desired outcome.

  - Maybe someone can work from what's provided here, to reach the next step. I'll work on this again later.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a reproducible dataframe
np.random.seed(365)
df_R = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 36)), columns=df_R_cols)
df_H = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 72)), columns=df_H_cols)

# create groups of column names: 18 groups
dfh_groups = [df_H.columns[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(df_H.columns), 4)]
dfr_groups = [df_R.columns[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(df_R.columns), 2)]

# create empty lists for pandas Series
x_series = list()
z_series = list()
both_series = list()

for i in range(len(dfr_groups)):

    # print the groups
    print(dfr_groups[i])
    print(dfh_groups[i])
    
    # extract the groups of column names
    rx, rz = dfr_groups[i]
    htx, hbx, htz, hbz = dfh_groups[i]
    
    # check if _mean is between _top & _bottom
    x_between = (df_R.loc[:, rx] < df_H.loc[:, htx]) & (df_R.loc[:, rx] > df_H.loc[:, hbx])
    z_between = (df_R.loc[:, rz] < df_H.loc[:, htz]) & (df_R.loc[:, rz] > df_H.loc[:, hbz])
    
    # check if x & z meet the criteria
    both_between = x_between & z_between
    
    # name the pandas Series
    name = rx.split('_')[0]
    x_between.rename(f'{name}_x', inplace=True)
    z_between.rename(f'{name}_z', inplace=True)
    both_between.rename(f'{name}_xz', inplace=True)
    
    # append Series to lists
    x_series.append(x_between)
    z_series.append(z_between)
    both_series.append(both_between)

    # the following section of the loop is only used for visualization
    # it is not necessary, other that for the plots

    # plot
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(16, 6))
    ax1.plot(df_R.loc[:, rz], df_R.loc[:, rx], label='mid')
    ax1.plot(df_H.loc[:, htz], df_H.loc[:, htx], label='top')
    ax1.plot(df_H.loc[:, hbz], df_H.loc[:, hbx], label='bottom')
    ax1.set_title(f'{name}\nboth: {both_between.mean()}\nx: {x_between.mean()}\nz: {z_between.mean()}')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Z-val')
    ax1.set_ylabel('X-val')
    ax1.legend()
    
    # plot x, z, and mean with respect to the index
    ax2.plot(df_R.index, df_R.loc[:, rx], label='x_mean')
    ax2.plot(df_H.index, df_H.loc[:, htx], label='x_top')
    ax2.plot(df_H.index, df_H.loc[:, hbx], label='x_bot')
    
    ax2.plot(df_R.index, df_R.loc[:, rz], label='z_mean')
    ax2.plot(df_H.index, df_H.loc[:, htz], label='z_top')
    ax2.plot(df_H.index, df_H.loc[:, hbz], label='z_bot')
    
    ax2.set_title('top, bottom and mean plotted with the x-axis as the index')
    ax2.legend()
    plt.show()
    

# concat all the Series into dataframes and set the type to int
df_x_between = pd.concat(x_series, axis=1).astype(int)
df_z_between = pd.concat(z_series, axis=1).astype(int)
df_both_between = pd.concat(both_series, axis=1).astype(int)

# calculate the mean
df_both_between.mean(axis=0).to_frame().T
```

- This plot is generated with the real data, which was provided by the OP.
- The following plot demonstrates why the currently implemented conditions do not work as desired.

  - For example, `(val < df_H_top_X.iloc[i,c]) & (val > df_H_bottom_X.iloc[i,c])` from the OP, is implemented above, with `x_between`.
  - The right plot shows that the specified conditions won't help determine when `mid` is between `top` and `bottom`, as shown in the left plot.

[image]

Comment: I ran this on my dataset but the df_both_between is all 0s, which I know can't be true from looking at the plots

Comment: @CentauriAurelius It worked for the test data. But for the time being, what did it get for `df_x_between` and `df_z_between`. Does that look correct

Comment: There are some 1s in those two dataframes but less than I'd expect. I tried adding you to a stackoverflow chat to avoid discussion in the comments as I received a warning on another post about that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228721/discussion-between-trenton-mckinney-and-centauriaurelius).

Comment: The chart is a good demonstration of the issue at hand.  Essentially, the visual question of: Given two "parallel" black paths in 2-D, what percentage of the red path is covered inside is a geometric one.   This does not really consider the time component at all. The other question, which is about, at a given point in time, given the 3 points b_top, b_bottom, r_mean, whether it is in-between is a different question that is quite trivial.  May be, what is the actual motive behind the question, so that we can address what is "wanted"?

Comment: @CentauriAurelius You should add this clarification to the question as an edit. Comments get deleted.

Comment: I borrowed some code from your answer for mine. It saved me a lot of thinking. I hope a upvote as rental fee is okay. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

#### I'm going to take a slightly different route.  This is still rough, so criticism/suggestions are welcome! (Why am I yelling?!)

If possible, get all your tuples into an iterable:

```
a_rng = range(3)
b_rng = range(1, 3)
c_rng = range(1, 4)
all_my_tuples = [(a, b, c) for a in a_rng for b in b_rng for c in c_rng]
```

#### List comprehension the columns with f-strings:

```
df_R_cols = [f"{x}_mean_{e}" for x in all_my_tuples for e in ["X","Z",]]
df_H_cols = [f"{x}_{pos}_{e}" for x in all_my_tuples for e in ["X","Z",] for pos in ["top", "bottom",]]
```

#### Create huge dataframe

```
df_R_H = pd.merge(df_R, df_H, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

#### Use `pandas.query()` to create and execute dynamic query strings:

#### Create output dataframe using all_my_tuples as index

```
df_fin = pd.DataFrame(index = map(str, all_my_tuples), columns=["n_found",])

# Iterate tuple elements
for t in all_my_tuples:
    # Create query list.
    qry_ = []
    # Repeat same query creation process for X and Z.
    for xz in ["X", "Z"]:
        qry_.append(f"(`{t}_mean_{xz}` < `{t}_top_{xz}` & `{t}_mean_{xz}` > `{t}_bottom_{xz}`)")

    # Join to create full query and execute into new dataframe
    qry = " & ".join(qry_)
    # print(qry)
    dft = df_R_H.query(qry)

    # Update dataframe with row count
    if not (dft) is None:
        df_fin.loc[f"{t}", "n_found"] = dft.shape[0]
    else:
        df_fin.loc[f"{t}", "n_found"] = 0
```

## Then divide by the row count of one of the dataframe.

```
df_fin["n_mean"] = df_fin.loc[:, "n_found"].apply(lambda q: q / df_R.shape[0])
```

Output is something like the following:

```
          n_found  n_mean
(0, 1, 1)      27   0.027
(0, 1, 2)      34   0.034
(0, 1, 3)      25   0.025
(0, 2, 1)      23   0.023
(0, 2, 2)      31   0.031
(0, 2, 3)      29   0.029
(1, 1, 1)      22   0.022
(1, 1, 2)      23   0.023
(1, 1, 3)      22   0.022
(1, 2, 1)      21   0.021
(1, 2, 2)      22   0.022
(1, 2, 3)      27   0.027
(2, 1, 1)      29   0.029
(2, 1, 2)      35   0.035
(2, 1, 3)      25   0.025
(2, 2, 1)      29   0.029
(2, 2, 2)      23   0.023
(2, 2, 3)      32   0.032
```

Comment: Just tried this - In df_fin for (0, 1, 3) I got a mean value of .022, but looking at the plot its clear that more than 2.2% of the red trajectory falls within the two blacks. I think the solution will require that either the X or Z values are binned/bucketed as @tommy suggested rather than computing row-wise

Comment: I can send you a link to the pickled dataframes on GitHub via chat

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will check it out!  My best guess is that using random to generate data samples will put data that you want on the bottom on the top, and vice versa.  When I ran the script with just 100 rows, it ended up capturing something like 4 rows for a given condition, but my eyeballs confirmed that the conditions were being met.

Comment: If I query (0, 1, 3) for the Z values, I only get 18 results.  From those 18 results, it doesn't look like any of the X constraints would work.  Unless I'm reading the data incorrectly.  Screenshot -> https://i.imgur.com/AgWqzrm.png

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. The screenshot shows only the last 18 values (out of 1000). But if you are saying that checking if the mean is below the top and above the bottom wouldnt work - you are correct. The solution needs to be able to check if the mean trajectory is between the two black trajectories some other way.

Comment: So, it's pretty much indifferent to top and bottom?  I just want to be sure I understand and I think I do, but it could be something like: `top_Z < mean_Z < bottom_Z` or `top_Z > mean_Z > bottom_Z`.  In either case, it can't be `top_Z > mean_Z < bottom_Z` or `top_Z < mean_Z > bottom_Z`, which would put it outside the scope at least one condition.

Comment: Yes Top and Bottom 'switch' sometimes for different groups (i.e, (0,1,3) vs (2,2,3). However, within each group, they do not swtich. So I was thinking maybe adding a check for each group to see whether X is larger/smaller for the top vs bottom trajectory, then applying the corresponding condition.